# Visifire/WPF databinding issues (Visifire v3.6.8)

Tags: wpf, data-binding, visifire

I have a very basic databinding issue with the Visifire WPF charting tool in the last open-source version, v3.6.8, before it became commercial. I want to bind an ObservableCollection<> to the DataSource-Property of a DataSeries. It just doesn't work when I bind the property in XAML. When I bind the data in the code behind, it works fine.

I am using the collection for a DataGrid as well and there everything works fine.

The output log doesn't show any binding issues.

The get/set accessors of the DataSource property of the DataSeries object are never accessed when binding the property in XAML, I just don't get why. The dependency property is registered at creation of the DataSeries object.

Are there any known issues with this or am I missing something basic?

The XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grid" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding TransverseParallelShearLCS}"></DataGrid>

<Charts:Chart Grid.Column="1" x:Name="chart" ZoomingEnabled="True" AnimatedUpdate="True" ScrollingEnabled="False">
    <Charts:Chart.Series>
        <Charts:DataSeries RenderAs="Line" DataSource="{Binding TransverseParallelShearLCS}" AutoFitToPlotArea="True">                                                    
        <Charts:DataSeries.DataMappings>
              <Charts:DataMapping MemberName="XValue" Path="X"></Charts:DataMapping>
              <Charts:DataMapping MemberName="YValue" Path="Y"></Charts:DataMapping>
        </Charts:DataSeries.DataMappings> 
        </Charts:DataSeries>
     </Charts:Chart.Series>
</Charts:Chart>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below sample example from Visifire [Example Area](http://visifire.com/silverlight_examples.php) and check.

http://visifire.com/silverlight_examples_details.php?id=10

Comment: Thank you very much, but after trying everything for hours I was fed up, and rebuilt my GUI with the OxyPlot library. Everything worked within minutes.